# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Usuario.T003_FK_COORDENACAO'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou com um problema no DropDownListFor, ele está populado com dados do banco.

Código Controller.

```
var coordenacaoList = db.VW004_LISTAR_COORDENACAO.ToList();
        ViewBag.CoordenacaoList = new SelectList(coordenacaoList, "ID_COORDENACAO", "TITULO_COORDENACAO");
```

View.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Usuario.T003_FK_COORDENACAO, (SelectList)ViewBag.CoordenacaoList, " Selecione uma Coordenação", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Só que quando vou fazer o post em uma procedure, me da esse erro.

[image: Imagem de Erro]

Controller.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Cadastrar(T001_USUARIO obj)
    {
        try
        {

            SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@MATRICULA_CADASTRADA", obj.T001_MATRICULA);
            SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@NOME", obj.T001_NOME_USUARIO);
            SqlParameter param3 = new SqlParameter("@PERFIL", obj.T002_FK_PERFIL);
            SqlParameter param4 = new SqlParameter("@COORD", obj.T003_FK_COORDENACAO);
            var db = new AppModel();

            var data = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SP001_CADASTRA_USUARIO @MATRICULA_CADASTRADA, @NOME, @PERFIL, @COORD", param1, param2, param3, param4);

            return RedirectToAction("Listar");

        }
        catch
        {           
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Controller GET.

```
public ActionResult Cadastrar()
    {

        AppModel db = new AppModel();

        var coordenacaoList = db.T003_COORDENACAO.ToList();
        ViewBag.CoordenacaoList = new SelectList(coordenacaoList, "T003_ID_COORDENACAO", "T003_DESC_COORD");

        var perfilList = db.VW005_LISTAR_PERFIL.ToList();
        ViewBag.PerfilList = new SelectList(perfilList, "T002_ID_PERFIL", "T002_DESC_PERFIL");


        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Lucas, por favor, coloque o código do seu model.

Comment: public partial class T001_USUARIO
    {
        public int T001_ID_USUARIO { get; set; }
        public string T001_MATRICULA { get; set; }
        public string T001_NOME_USUARIO { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> T001_ATIVO { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> T002_FK_PERFIL { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> T003_FK_COORDENACAO { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Lucas, Boa tarde

Acredito que esse erro esta acontecendo no retorno do seu metodo Post, pois a lista "(SelectList)ViewBag.CoordenacaoList" deve estar null, garanta que todas as listas tem valores antes de retornar a view.

No seu metodo HttpPost

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Cadastrar(T001_USUARIO obj)
{
    try
        {
            AppModel db = new AppModel();

            SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@MATRICULA_CADASTRADA", obj.T001_MATRICULA);
            SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@NOME", obj.T001_NOME_USUARIO);
            SqlParameter param3 = new SqlParameter("@PERFIL", obj.T002_FK_PERFIL);
            SqlParameter param4 = new SqlParameter("@COORD", obj.T003_FK_COORDENACAO);
            var db = new AppModel();

            var data = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SP001_CADASTRA_USUARIO @MATRICULA_CADASTRADA, @NOME, @PERFIL, @COORD", param1, param2, param3, param4);

            return RedirectToAction("Listar");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {         

            var coordenacaoList = db.T003_COORDENACAO.ToList();
    ViewBag.CoordenacaoList = new SelectList(coordenacaoList, "T003_ID_COORDENACAO", "T003_DESC_COORD");

    var perfilList = db.VW005_LISTAR_PERFIL.ToList();
    ViewBag.PerfilList = new SelectList(perfilList, "T002_ID_PERFIL", "T002_DESC_PERFIL");


            return View(obj);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Você poderia me dizer como fazer isso, sou novo no C#.

Comment: voce pode por exemplo adicionar o mesmo trecho de codigo que voce user na Action "HttpGet".

    var coordenacaoList = db.VW004_LISTAR_COORDENACAO.ToList();
        ViewBag.CoordenacaoList = new SelectList(coordenacaoList, "ID_COORDENACAO", "TITULO_COORDENACAO");

adicione o codigo acima antes do Return View()

Comment: Não entendi como fazer isso, vou editar minha pergunta e colocar o controller para você da uma olhada.

Comment: Adicione tambem o methodo HttpGet

Comment: Estou fazendo 2 DropDownList

Comment: Não funcionou, cai direto no catch, não apresenta mensagem de erro.

Comment: antes ja estava caindo no try catch porque se nao ele nao retornaria para a mesma pagina, mas mesmo assim agora voce pode ver atraves da variavel ex qual foi o erro